# Magento2 - post dispatch observers

Tags: magento2, event-observer

I was wondering if the Magento trigger the `postdispatch` observers or not if the current controller action failed to pass the validation?  For example, we have an observer created for action `controller_action_postdispatch_customer_account_createpost`so if the scenario failed to pass the `customer_account_createPost` action (i-e may be some validation which Magento handle) so my `controller_action_postdispatch` will still be executed in the failed scenario or it will only be executed in the success scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found it by myself, Magento does not care if the event action `return true/false`, it will process the `postdispatch` observer in anyway.